# Отличие хэш суммы MD5 на основе текста и на основе файла

Tags: c#, visual-studio, http, хеширование, md5

Есть программа, суть которой принимать HTTP запрос с файлом и в ответе нужно отправить MD5 хэш сумму.
Я выяснил, что можно считать хэш на основе текста и на основе файла и в некоторых моментах они отличаются, но из-за чего - я не понял.

Изучив примеры, написал следующий код

```
FileStream fstream = File.OpenRead(pathStr + @"\" + partnerName + @"\IN\" + strname);
byte[] array = new byte[fstream.Length];
fstream.Read(array, 0, array.Length);
string textFromFile = win1251.GetString(array);
MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] retVal = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(textFromFile));
fstream.Close();
```

Проблема вот в чем. Если я собираю в VS2019 консольное приложение с этим кодом, то у меня хэш считается как мне надо - из текста. НО если попытаться собрать проект как службу Windows, то этот же самый код считает сумму из файла. Проверяю я это в Notepad++.

Помогите научить сборку службы Windows считать хэш на основе текста

Comment: [File.ReadAllText](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netcore-3.1) позволит сразу содержимое файла получить без всяких манипуляций со стримами и т.д.

Comment: Разница может состоять в значении `Encoding.Default` проверь чем это равно в одном и другом случае

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что вы перекодируете файл в строку и обратно, используя разные кодировки для чтения и записи. Но можно вообще без перекодировок.

```csharp
byte[] array = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(pathStr, partnerName, "IN", strname));
MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] retVal = md5.ComputeHash(array);

Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(retVal).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();
```

Вот так вот просто.

Чтобы не грузить весь файл в память, можно считать хэш по данным из потока

```csharp
MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] retVal;
using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(pathStr, partnerName, "IN", strname)))
{
    retVal = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
}
```

Если нужна перекодировка из Win-1251 в UTF-8, то получится вот так

```csharp
byte[] array = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(pathStr, partnerName, "IN", strname));
string text = win1251.GetString(array);
MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] retVal = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
```

Comment: Ваш код отработал точно так же - результат не был получен

Comment: @Dayzee что значит из текста, и из файла, в чем разница? Этот код работает по-разному, когда запущен в службе и в приложении? Если честно, здесь нечему работать по-разному. Откуда берутся данные для расчета дайджеста, в обоих случаях из одного и того же файла? Вы уверены, что служба смогла успешно прочитать файл, имеет ли она к нему доступ? И что значит "из текста"? Хэш считается только на основе байтового массива данных.

Comment: @Dayzee Еще вопрос, откуда и зачем вам там `win1251` кодировка? У вас Windows XP? Начиная с Windows 7 кодировка системы по умолчанию для текстовых файлов - `UTF-8`.

Comment: @Dayzee дополнил ответ на случай, если у вас там потоки.

Comment: Да, верно, нод работает в консольном приложении и в службе по разному. Кодировка Winsows-1251, потому что файлы которые я принимаю имеют эту кодировку. Служба читает файл, я пробовал выводить содержимое. Проблема не в кодировке, я думаю, это из-за службы. Тк если открыть xml файл в notepadd++ и его средствами посчитать хэш Инструменты->MD5->Сгенерировать... и вставить текст из файла, то получится хэш который мне нужен, а Инструменты->MD5->Сгенерировать из файлов, то получается другой хэн, такой же как считает служба.

Comment: @Dayzee проблема скорее всего кроется в кодировке. Хэш считается из бинарных данных, и должен считаться из бинарных данных. Там где вы считаете его из текста - это не правильный подход. Но можно предположить, что хэш на основе текста в кодировке win-1251 вы считаете не правильным, а хэш на основе кодировки UTF-8 - правильным, или наоборот. Здесь дело именно в кодировках, а не в текстах и файлах. Скажите, вам нужно перекодировать текст в UTF-8 до расчета хеша, я правильно понимаю? Какой потенциальный размер самого большого такого файла?

Comment: @Dayzee обновил ответ.

Comment: Скорее наоборот, хеш на основе win1251 будет верным. Если вы говорите, что это из-за кодировки, то почему когда я меняю в коде `md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(textFromFile))` на `md5.ComputeHash(win1251.GetBytes(textFromFile))` хэш считается такой же. Я по этой логике откинул вариант с неправильной кодировкой

Comment: @Dayzee наверное потому что в файле нет не-ASCII символов, поэтому и одинаково получается? Но могут быть еще разные переносы строк CRLF или LF. Вообще, тот код, который я вам дал в самом начале, он и считаешь хэш именно из того, что в файле, такой хэш не может быть не правильным. И что за веб-сервис такой, который данные в Win-1251 отдает, давно написан?

Comment: к тому же мне не дает покоя тот факт, что тот же самый код 1 в 1 скопированный, но в консольном приложении выдает хэш какой мне и нужен. Использую файл для теста один и тот же

Comment: @Dayzee `Encoding.Default.GetBytes` может иметь разное значение в разном окружении и выдавать разный набор байт, имейте это в виду. Если вам нужно что-то одинаковое, не используйте `Default`. Пробуйте `Unicode` или `UTF8` как в дополненной части ответа.

Comment: Последний код в вашем ответе дал ожидаемый результат. Благодарю за помощь!